# Xcode and saving versions

Tags: xcode, multiple-versions

I'm relatively new to Xcode (am using 4.5.2 on Lion) and have struggled to find a way to do what would be straightforward in most applications, namely, to save the current version of a project with a new name, so that I can step backward to a previous version if it was working better.

I attempted to use the snapshots feature, and then when I used the Restore Snapshot option, I did not get back the code that had been present in the snapshot I was restoring. So what exactly is snapshot including? And in any case, how can I achieve this seemingly simple goal of being able to return to a previous version of a project?

thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=git+XCode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gbv=1&sei=RaoPUa_iCqq90QGStIG4BA

Comment: Use `git`; that's what it's for.

Comment: OK - I did read about git. But is it possible to create a git for a project that's already been started? It's not obvious to me how it would be done.